# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the $x$-axis. $y=x^{3/2}$, $y=8$, $x=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the $x$-axis.

$y=x^{3/2}$, $y=8$, $x=0$

What I did:

$y=x^{3/2}\Rightarrow x=y^{2/3}$

$Circumference= 2\pi(8-y)$

$Height=(4-y^{2/3})$

$Surface Area =2\pi(8-y)(4-y^{2/3})$

$Volume=2\pi\int _{ 0 }^{ 8 }{ (8-y)(4-y^{2/3})dy} $

$=2\pi\int _{ 0 }^{ 8 }{ 32-8y^{2/3}-4y+y^{5/3}dy}$

$=2\pi[32y-\frac{24y^{5/3}}{5}-2y^2+\frac{3y^{8/3}}{8}]_{0}^{8}$

$=2\pi[32(8)-\frac{24(8)^{5/3}}{5}-2(8)^2+\frac{3(8)^{8/3}}{8}]-2\pi[0]$

$=2\pi[256-\frac{768}{5}-128+\frac{768}{8}]$

$=2\pi(\frac{352}{5})$

$=\frac{704\pi}{5}$

---

My final answer seems to be wrong, but I am not sure where I went wrong in my (wrong) solution for this problem. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Is that all that is wrong? (up to the point that I set up the integral). Why is it $0$ to $4$? I don't get it..

Comment: Limits of 0 to 8 would apply if you rotated the curve about the $y$-axis. But $8=x^{3/2}$ means $x=4$, and the integral would then be $\int_0^4\pi(8^2-x^3)\ dx$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel It seems to me that you just used the washer method. Was my setup of the shell method correct? (other than the limits of integration).

Comment: Actually, if you're using shell the limits are correct. The integrand is wrong though; it should be just $y^{5/3}$, so you get $192\pi$ as the answer, the same as what I got wih washer.

Comment: Indeed, it would be $\int _0^8 2\times\pi\times(xy) dy$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Just $y^{5/3}$? What? I'm sorry, I am confused now.

Comment: OK, your _limits_ are set up correctly. But the _integrand_ of the shell method is $yf^{-1}(y)$ where $y=f(x)=x^{3/2}$ is what you already have. Then $f^{-1}(y)=y^{2/3}$, so the integrand is $y^{5/3}$ and the volume $2\pi\int_0^8y^{5/3}\ dy$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel How did you just get $y^{5/3}$? What was the circumference of the circle on the shell? The height of the shell? The answer alone doesn't really help me, sorry. I am trying to understand what exactly led you to this.

Comment: The circumference and the surface area are completely irrelevant. I was referring to the formula on the Wikipedia article for [shell integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration) - go have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the revolution is around the $x$-axis, each cylindrical shell at $x$ for $x\in [0,4]$ (where $4=8^{3/2}$) is actually an annulus with inner radius $r(x)=x^{3/2}$ and outer radius $R(x)=8$.

The volume of this shell is $(\pi R^2(x) -\pi r^2(x))\cdot dx$. Hence the total volume can be obtained by "summing" the volumes of all these thin shells,
$$\int_{x=0}^4 (\pi R^2(x) -\pi r^2(x))\cdot dx=\pi\int_{0}^4 (8^2 -x^3)\cdot dx=\pi \left[64x-\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^4= 192\pi.$$

Note that if the revolution is around the $y$-axis, the solid is different and its volume is
$$\int_{y=0}^8 \pi (y^{2/3})^2\cdot dy=\pi \left[\frac{y^{7/3}}{7/3}\right]_0^8=\frac{384\pi}{7}.$$